# XMLUnit: Unable to attach custom DifferenceListener using overrideDifferenceListener

Tags: java, xmlunit

I am unable to attach custom diff listener using overrideDifferenceListener method.

```
    String xml1 = readFile("data/xml1.xml", Charset.defaultCharset());
    String xml2 = readFile("data/xml2.xml", Charset.defaultCharset());

    Diff xmlDiff = new Diff(xml1, xml2);

    xmlDiff.overrideDifferenceListener(new MyDiffListener(listConsideredForDiff));
    assertTrue(xmlDiff.similar());
```

The custom diff class

```
class MyDiffListener implements DifferenceListener{
    private Set<String> consideredList = new HashSet<String>(); // list to consider for difference

    public MyDiffListener(ArrayList<String> list) {

        for(String element: list){
            consideredList.add(element);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int differenceFound(Difference diff) {

        if (diff.getId() == DifferenceConstants.TEXT_VALUE_ID){
            if(!consideredList.contains(diff.getControlNodeDetail().getNode().getParentNode().getNodeName())){
                return DifferenceListener.RETURN_ACCEPT_DIFFERENCE;
            }
        }
        return DifferenceListener.RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL;

    }

    @Override
    public void skippedComparison(Node arg0, Node arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

program control isnt hitting the breakpoint inside differenceFound method of MyDiffListener when I debug.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    String xml1 = "<root><a/></root>";
    String xml2 = "<root><b/></root>";

    Diff xmlDiff = new Diff(xml1, xml2);
    xmlDiff.overrideDifferenceListener(new DifferenceListener() {
            @Override
            public int differenceFound(Difference diff) {
                System.err.println("called: " + diff);
                return RETURN_ACCEPT_DIFFERENCE;
            }
            @Override
            public void skippedComparison(Node arg0, Node arg1) { }
        });
    xmlDiff.similar();
```

emits

```
called: Expected element tag name 'a' but was 'b' - comparing <a...> at /root[1]/a[1] to <b...> at /root[1]/b[1]
```

Maybe your documents do not contain any differences or your breakpoint is watching the wrong line?